# Is there a way to tell when git last did a gc?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that seems to be taking up a lot of space.  I know `git gc` might reduce the size, but I also know it can take some time and resources to run.

Is there a way to check the date that git last did a gc, in order to get a better idea of whether running it today would just be wasting my time?

Comment: Err, how big is your repo? `git gc` should only run for a few seconds on even pretty large repositories. It will also run automatically unless you've explicitly turned that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't tell when git last ran gc, and you shouldn't care either. As others have told you already, git will run gc automatically when it is needed.

If you do not have time to wait for it at that moment - interrupt it with ctrl+c.

You can [count](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-count-objects) the loose (non-packed) objects like this:

```
$ git count-objects
```

Comment: I think `git count-objects` is supposed to give that number, although it gave a slightly different answer than your command.

Comment: Nice! My find command will count the subfolders under the objects tree in addition to the actual commit objects. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git gc --auto
```

Documentation:

> With this option, git gc checks whether any housekeeping is required;
>   if not, it exits without performing any work. Some git commands run
>   git gc --auto after performing operations that could create many loose
>   objects.